# Copying SSH Key-Pair Generated by Putty to MacOS

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

i have a target BSD machine where i connect to from my windows box, i copied the public and private key pairs that are generated by putty and i'm trying to use them on a different laptop with Mac OS. I copied the keys to ~/.ssh/ folder here on MAC but they are failing to connect to the BSD machine. these are my logs.

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/username/.ssh/public
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /Users/username/.ssh/public.
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug2: bad passphrase given, try again...
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /Users/username/.ssh/public.
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug2: no passphrase given, try next key
```

What else did i forgot? Thanks in advance

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/232362/how-to-convert-ppk-key-to-openssh-key-under-linux

Answer (score 1):

In puttygen you have an option in Conversions to export your key to a OpenSSH key. You might want to try export it using this function.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an access to my Windows machine right now. All I have is the usb that contains the public and private keys and macbook, is there any way I can still use these keys to access the target machine? Thanks.